# compositing mist flashing

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a scene that I have rendered with composited mist. The rest of the scene is working fine other than this section:
https://youtu.be/9N2IVqZxa_0

I initially thought it had to do with a harsh gradient within the mist compositor as I used a colour ramp. However, I changed the colour ramp settings to B-spline which has a smoother gradient and it didn't help.
Here is a screenshot of my compositor node setup.
This project is time sensitive so any help would be appreciated.

[image: node setup]

Comment: Check the output of the Normalizer ... since it is an animation there is a chance there is a difference in depth from frame to frame so normalised output differs accordingly. Or try to mute Denoiser (I saw some glitches in work of others).

Comment: @vklidu I tried muting the denoiser and it did not work. How do I check the output of the normalizer and what am I checking for?

Comment: just connect Normalizer to output (Composite node) and render it... if it is flashing ...

Comment: Instead of the normalizer node use a map range node which will be consistent across all frames or use the mist pass. you can change the mist start end and interpolation settings in the world properties